Select photos on the tenth day of each month and trim their description in PostgreSQL
I have a table photos with columns description and capture_date. I need to:

Extract photos captured on the 10th day of any month.
Summarize the description to be up to 10 characters long, including an ellipsis if the original description is longer than 10 characters.
Format the capture_date as 'DD.MM HH24:MI'.

Here is the query I have tried:
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN LENGTH(description) > 10 THEN SUBSTRING(description, 1, 7) || '...'
    ELSE description
  END AS summary,
  TO_CHAR(capture_date, 'DD.MM HH24:MI') AS date
FROM photos
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM capture_date) = 10
ORDER BY capture_date DESC;


There's a special single character for ellipsis: …. Cut off at character 10 and replace it with that. You forgot to ask the question but if it's "would that work?", then yes, it does work.

"Format the capture_date as 'DD.MM HH24:MI'." <-- This should not be done in SQL, because date and value formatting is a presentation-layer concern, whereas it's important to maintain types for as long as possible in a data-flow.
